# MKNetworking frozen operation

Tags: ios, mknetworkkit

I am using MKNetworkKit. I have successfully added the package and uploaded to server.
However I was not able to activate the frozen operations. I have added the line

```
[self.flOperation setFreezable:YES];
```

Are required by the kit. I then manually disabled the network from my device. When activated back again, the kit never seam to try sending the file again to the server.

Did anyone experience this before? I use the latest version from github.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of your request ? GET operations are not freezable and MKNetworkKit ignores your call to setFreezable if your operation is a “GET” operation.

Here is an extract of MKNetWorkOperation.m

```
- (void)setFreezable:(BOOL)flag
{
    // get method cannot be frozen.
    // No point in freezing a method that doesn't change server state.
    if([self.request.HTTPMethod isEqualToString:@"GET"] && flag) return;
    _freezable = flag;

    if(_freezable && self.uniqueId == nil)
    self.uniqueId = [NSString uniqueString];
}
```

Comment: it is not a get request. it is a post request